# simplification issues

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The first are from an old paper, dealing with the evaluation of elastic Green function in a transversely isotropic medium (Hill 1964).

```
Hill1 = ((a4 z[1]^2 + a1 z[2]^2 + a5 z[3]^2) (a5 (z[1]^2 + z[2]^2) + 
      a2 z[3]^2) - 
   z[2]^2 z[3]^2 a3^2)/((a4 (z[1]^2 + z[2]^2) + 
     a5 z[3]^2) ((a5 (z[1]^2 + z[2]^2) + 
        a2 z[3]^2) (a1 (z[1]^2 + z[2]^2) + a5 z[3]^2) - 
     a3^2 (z[1]^2 + z[2]^2) z[3]^2));

Hill2 = (z[1] z[2]^2 z[3] (a1 - a4) a3 - 
   z[1] z[3] a3 (a4 z[1]^2 + a1 z[2]^2 + 
      a5 z[3]^2))/((a4 (z[1]^2 + z[2]^2) + 
     a5 z[3]^2) ((a5 (z[1]^2 + z[2]^2) + 
        a2 z[3]^2) (a1 (z[1]^2 + z[2]^2) + a5 z[3]^2) - 
     a3^2 (z[1]^2 + z[2]^2) z[3]^2));
```

The following are the corresponding Mathematica expressions resulting from a 3X3 matrix inversion.

```
mat1 = (a5 (z[1]^2 + z[2]^2) (a4 z[1]^2 + 
        a1 z[2]^2) + ((a2 a4 + a5^2) z[1]^2 + (a1 a2 - a3^2 + a5^2) z[
          2]^2) z[3]^2 + 
     a2 a5 z[3]^4)/(a1 a4 a5 (z[1]^2 + 
        z[2]^2)^3 + ((a1 a2 - a3^2) a4 + (a1 + a4) a5^2) (z[1]^2 + 
        z[2]^2)^2 z[3]^2 + 
     a5 (-a3^2 + a2 (a1 + a4) + a5^2) (z[1]^2 + z[2]^2) z[3]^4 + 
     a2 a5^2 z[3]^6);

mat2 = -((a3 z[1] z[3])/(
   a1 a5 (z[1]^2 + z[2]^2)^2 + (a1 a2 - a3^2 + a5^2) (z[1]^2 + 
       z[2]^2) z[3]^2 + a2 a5 z[3]^4));

In[165]:= {mat1 - Hill1, mat2 - Hill2} // Together

Out[165]= {0, 0}

In[170]:= {mat1 == Hill1, mat2 == Hill2} // Simplify

Out[170]= {True, True}
```

Any ideas of how "pushing" Mathematica to simplify mat1 to Hill1 and mat2 to Hill2?

Thank you very much.

P.S.

Even if it was not needed for the above commands I should add that

z[i], i=1,2,3, satisfy `z[1]^2+z[2]^2+z[3]^2=1`.

Comment: Usually trying to force Mathematica into writing an equation in a particular form can drive you nuts. After all, what do you achieve? You already know both forms are equivalent ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Belisarius that simplification attempts can drive you nuts.  It seems especially unlikely that `mat2` can be simplified easily into `Hill2`, because `mat2` is the simpler form to begin with.  However, it is straightforward to simplify each pair into the *same* forms.  Use

```
FullSimplify[Expand[Hill1]];
FullSimplify[Expand[mat1]];
FullSimplify[Expand[Hill2]];
FullSimplify[Expand[mat2]];
```

Note that `FullSimplify` works better than `Simplify` here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Because `counta[z_] := Count[z, a_, Infinity]` gives a smaller `Count` for `Hill1` (130) than for `mat1` (158), I thought that using `ComplexityFunction -> counta` in my Answer above might drive `mat1` to `Hill1`, but it does not.  Strange.

Comment: I guess that `FullSimplify[Expand[Hill1]];
FullSimplify[Expand[mat1]];
FullSimplify[Expand[Hill2]];
FullSimplify[Expand[mat2]];` is the best we can get. Myself, I am pretty satisfied with your answer.